# How are gestures stored in android

Tags: android

How are gestures stored in android.Are they stored as an image (jpeg etc) or are they stored in any other format.

Comment: Doesn't makes sense. Please elaborate.

Comment: When the user creates a gesture using gesturebuilder it is stored in the sdcard.I want to know how the gesture is stored.

Comment: Maybe a gesture is an array of gesturepoints?

Answer (score 4):

Gestures package: `android.gesture`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/Gesture.html

> A gesture is a hand-drawn shape on a touch screen. It can have one or multiple strokes. Each stroke is a sequence of timed points. A user-defined gesture can be recognized by a GestureLibrary and a built-in alphabet gesture can be recognized by a LetterRecognizer.

That does mean that every gesture is saved as sequence of `GestureStroke`, where each GestureStroke is defined by more than two timed points of type `GesturePoint`. Gestures are combined into file containing `GestureLibrary` object. Library is able to parse this library file, loaded by `GestureLibraries::fromFile([String or File argument])`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureLibraries.html#fromFile(java.io.File)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureLibrary.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureStroke.html